# Get the name of a JObject in Json.Net

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I have a `JObject` equal to:

```
"Info":
{
    "View":"A",
    "Product":"B",
    "Offer":"Offer1",
    "Demo":"body {background-color:red;} #box {border:dotted 50px red;}",
    "Log":false
}
```

How can I return the name of the object, "Info"?

I am currently using the `Path` property like so:

```
jObject.Name = jObject.Path.Substring(jObject.Path.jObject('.') + 1);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `Info` is not an array, it's an object.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In JSON, objects themselves do not have names.  An object is just a container for a collection of name-value pairs, beginning and ending with curly braces.  So what you have above is a fragment of a larger body of JSON.  There must be an outer object to contain it.  That outer object has a *property* with a name of `Info`, and the value of that property is the object you are referring to.

```
{
    "Info":
    {
        "View":"A",
        "Product":"B",
        "Offer":"Offer1",
        "Demo":"body {background-color:red;} #box {border:dotted 50px red;}",
        "Log":false
    }
}
```

In Json.Net, a `JObject` models a JSON object, and a `JProperty` models a name-value pair contained within a `JObject`.  Each `JObject` has a collection of `JProperties` which are its children, while each `JProperty` has a `Name` and a single child, its `Value`.

So, assuming you have a reference to the innermost `JObject` (containing the `View`, `Product` and `Offer` properties), you can get the name of its containing `JProperty` like this:

```
JProperty parentProp = (JProperty)jObject.Parent;
string name = parentProp.Name;  // "Info"
```

Comment: When I hover over Parent in VS, it shows as JContainer.  A cast to JProperty works, just wondering if there's anything to watch out for with that?

Comment: @twelveFunKeys A `JContainer` is any `JToken` that can contain another `JToken`, that is, `JArray`, `JObject` and `JProperty` but not `JValue`.  The `Parent` property is defined on the base `JToken` class because any `JToken` might have a parent, and that parent will always be a `JContainer` by definition.  The parent of a `JProperty` will always be a `JObject`.  The parent of a `JObject`, `JArray` or `JValue` could be either a `JProperty` or a `JArray`, but not a `JObject`.  So you do need to know how to cast it.  If you don't know the type, you can check the `Type` property before casting.