# Get list with KeyValuePairs from JSON node

Tags: c#, .net, json, wpf, keyvaluepair

I have the following JSON:

```
{ 
    "data":[{ 
        "from": "2017-11-22T10:00Z",
        "to": "2017-11-22T10:30Z",
        "intensity": {
            "forecast": 322,
            "actual": 343,
            "index": "high"
        }
    }]
}
```

Of which I want to extract the intensity properties as a `KeyValuePair` list.

What I did to access the list:

```
JObject parsed = JObject.Parse(JSON);
var list = parsed.SelectToken("data[0].intensity").ToList();
```

This gives me the following list of JToken objects:

```
"forecast": 322
"actual": 343
"index": "high"
```

How can I convert this to a `KeyValuePair<string, string>` list?

Comment: And what should be the key and the value in that list of JToken objects?

Comment: The idea is to get a list of forecast as key and 322 as value and so on...

Comment: You could possibly create a generic add method, like here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654752/can-i-create-a-dictionary-of-generic-types

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654752/can-i-create-a-dictionary-of-generic-types]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some extra searching I found the following post that gave the hint for the final solution: [Get Name of JObject in json.net using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000572/get-name-of-jobject-in-json-net-using-linq)

I implemented the following solution:

```
var parsed = JObject.Parse(JSON);
var list = parsed.SelectToken("data[0].intensity");
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyvaluelist = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

foreach (var item in list)
{
    JProperty prop = (JProperty)item;
    string key = prop.Name; 
    string value = (string)prop.Value;
    keyvaluelist.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value));
}
```

Comment: Considering circumstances wouldn't 'Dictonary<string, string>' be more appropiate?

Comment: The JSON input will be dynamic, so "data[0].intensity" will be a variable. That makes a dictionary a risk when the JSON has duplicate keys. Also, I use the list for creating columns/values in a SQLite database, so the performance of a dictionary is not needed.

Comment: Do I understand well that you expect something like: '"intensity": { "forecast": 322, "forecast": 340 ... }'? You have no control about the source objects?

Comment: Indeed, the input is coming from third parties which I have no control over. And not processing the JSON is not an option because of audit requirements.